# How to call the capture rate of the confidence interval

Tags: simulation, confidence-interval, precision

I have made a simulation study in order to evaluate the "efficiency" of a specific test method. I create some data and then I look whether the resulting CI of my my effect size estimate captures the true effect size. (As I am generating my test data I know what the true effect size is). Repeating this many times I get a proportion how often my CIs capture the true effect size. This is my measure for 'how good' my estimation method works. My qestion is: how should I call this proportion? Does it already have a name? Informally I was calling it 'precision', though precision has already another rather specific meaning.

Many thanks for any hints!
Bernhard

Comment: It is called [coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_probability).